# Jquery loading div before page starts actually loads

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a page that has to do quite a bit of work (5-6 seconds) of loading data from all over the place on the initial connection.  It is slow because of the api endpoints I am calling, I have no control over it.

Is there a way to get a loading div to show before it starts doing all of its data collection?

The below doesnt do anything. I believe its because the page already starts gathering data before it gets to the jquery.  I could be wrong.  myjs.js is the file name and it is the first thing loaded on my page.

```
$('body').on('load', function(){
    $body.addClass("loading");
});
```

and does the same thing

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $body.addClass("loading");
   });
```

In layman's terms:

1. User goes to https://somewebsite.com
2. Jquery loading div shows
3. other functions run to gather data
4. jquery loading div is removed.

This is in the laravel framework if that affects anything.

Comment: You should do the opposite, add `loading` class to the `body` in HTML source and remove it after fetch is done.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a pretty simple way to do this. I recently experienced something similar.

I did something like this:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    $('.jumping-dots-loader').slideUp(650);
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.jumping-dots-loader {
  width: 100vw !important;
  height: 100vh !important;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 99999999999999999999999;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 20% 35%;
  text-align: center;
}

.jumping-dots-loader span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(147, 194, 61, 1);
  margin: 35px 0.85rem;
}


/* Add in animation */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jumping-dots-loader">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>

<h1>
  Howsit going?
</h1>
```

If you go through [Mozilla's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) about the `document.readystatechange` event, you will see how the browser handles the loading order and can use this to your advantage. In my example, I add a container `div` which will cover the user's viewport. Then style some dots (add your own animation to them) which will be displayed while the document is loading. When the `load` state is reached, the placeholder `div` will be hidden and the loaded page is displayed.